# Is it possible to show the number of views precisely?

Tags: support, feature-request

Is it possible to show the number of views precisely? (the number of views from each question or answer added up individually)

Comment: Note that general stack exchange questions/feature requests will likely get more attention on the [global meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes, if you wan't to include bots, and double views... otherwise no.